# Suitability of Magento

Tags: magento

We would like to start a E-commerce website with about 20K products. The inventory of every product would be controlled at the city level. Each city in the country will have its own inventory count. Also, price and tax structure per city will differ. Assuming about 3000 cities in my country, I believe this will be a massive website.

Also, the webfront has to be a single-page application which currently Magento does not have. There will be periodic promotions per city. Certain products will be offered at a discount. The company may want to even sell vegetables. The cutsomer may purchase 0.25 kg onions.

The traffic on the site is expected to be similar to Amazon.

My question: Is Magento suitable to serve as a backend system for such a website with every city being modelled as either a site or a store?

Do you foresee any issues with Magento for such a system?

Thanks

Comment: You may not find the answer on SO. I will tell you from my experience with Magento Enterprise is that it's lacking a lot of basic ecommerce features. The admin side is slow and cumbersome, reporting might as well not exist and there are so many other things. Of all the apps that I maintain and develop for, Magento has been the biggest thorn in my side. **Full disclosure:** The only other experience I've had with ecommerce apps is osCommerce (years ago), smaller WordPress plugins and VirtueMart for Joomla!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the product catalog will be shared between the cities and only the stock would differ. If yes - unfortunately Magento does not support it OOTB(Out-Of-The-Box)  but there are some plugins for that which look promising (didnt use it though). As for the promotion and prices it is possible to manage them in website scope.

> The traffic on the site is expected to be similar to Amazon.

so how much? Because i believe Amazon doesn't publish the original traffic;-) I worked with Magento based pages with traffic over 100m pageviews/month and it is stable but of course performance tweeks are needed.

As for the question about the single-page front-end - I believe it is possible - i know a project where the frontend is almost single-page.

The best about Magento is that it is very easy to extend and customize (of course when having proper knowledge). But it has some performance issues (which with proper knowledge can be resolved..).

I hope that this answers more or less your question.